# Hashmap of type byte in java not byte []

Tags: java, hashmap, byte

There are different way to use `HashMap` in different types like `Map<Integer, String>` or `Map<List, byte[]>` ... etc so my question is can we use `Map<byte, byte> = new HashMap<byte, byte>()?`

Comment: What is stopping you from trying?

Comment: Get into the habit of being very exact with symbols. It's not `Map(Integer, String)`, but `Map<Integer, String>`.

Comment: Yes - just use the Object version - Byte